# Angular argument passed to closure is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

So I have something along those lines:

```
$scope.getStructs = function(path, save_to) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8001/www-root/' + path}).

         success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             console.log("Success:  " + data);
             save_to = data;
         }).

         error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             alert("Error: " + status);
         });
    });
```

And when I call the function like so:

```
$scope.getStructs("get_users.pl", $scope.users);
```

The function fetches the data from the server correctly, however the `$scope.users` variable is undefined. The question is - why ?

Comment: You are just copying the value of $scope.user while setting it as arguments to a function. There is no pass by reference in javascript, everything is  by value. In the case when you pass objects you are just passing the value of its reference. However in your case even if save_to hold the copy of reference of an object you are overwriting by doing `save_to = data`. So basically you would need to have your getStructs return a promise and have it chain through and assign it to your scope.

Comment: Oh I see. I had remembered it the other way around.

Comment: I see. I will rewrite the function. You should put it as a proper answer so I can select it when the timer expires.

Comment: Try something like this:- `$scope.getStructs = function (path) { return $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: 'http://localhost:8001/www-root/' + path }).  then(function (response) {     console.log("Success:  " + response.data);     return response.data;   }, function (response) {         alert("Error: " + response.status);       });     }` and consume it as  `$scope.getStructs("get_users.pl").then(function(data){ $scope.users = data });` However you could add a service which abstracts out all the http calls and use that in your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing in the variable, just return the promise and handle it per-call:

```
$scope.getStructs = function (path) {
 return $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: 'http://localhost:8001/www-root/' + path
 });
}

$scope.getStructs("get_users.pl").
 success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log("Success:  " + data);
     $scope.users = data;
 }).
 error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
     alert("Error: " + status);
 });
```

Edit:

It looks like you want to reuse this, so it should be a factory you can inject into any controller. Something like this:

```
(function() {
  function StructFactory($http) {
    return {
      get: function(path) {
        return $http.get(path);
    }
  }
  angular.module('MyFactories', [])
         .factory('StructFactory', StructFactory);
})();
```

Include the module in your app module:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', ['MyFactories']);
```

Then include the factory in your controller:

```
(function() {
  function MyController($scope, StructFactory) {
    $scope.getStructs = function() {
      StructFactory.get('get_users.pl')
        .success(function(data) {
          $scope.users = data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
          console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
  }
  app.controller('MyController', MyController);
})();
```

Now you can easily reuse the factory in all of your controllers. And you can simply add more methods (add, delete, etc) to the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Because the argument is just a copy of the variable.

```
var a = 10;
function b(arg){
  arg--;
  console.log(arg);
}
// it will create a temp variable same as `a`, and execute `temp--; console.log(temp)`
b(a); //9
// real `a` not change
console.log(a); //10
```